# SVN over HTTPS: how to hide or encrypt URLs?

Tags: encryption, svn, https

I run Apache over HTTPS and can see in the log file that a HTTP/1.1 request is made for every single file of my repository. And for every single file, the full URL is disclosed.

I need to access my repository from a location where I don't want sysadmins to look over my shoulder and see all these individual URLs. Of course I know they won't see file contents since I am using HTTPS or not HTTP, but I am really annoyed they can see URLs and as a consequence, file names.

Is there a way I can hide or encrypt HTTPS urls with SVN?
This would be great, as I would prefer not having to resort using svn+ssh, which does not easily/readily support path-based authorization, which I am heavily using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With HTTPS, the full URL is only visible to the client (your `svn` binary) and the server hosting the repository. In-transit, only the hostname you're connecting to is visible.

You can further protect yourself by using a VPN connection between your client and the server, or tunneling over SSH (not svn+ssh, but an direct [ssh tunnel](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/tunneling/)).

If you're concerned about the sysadmin of the box hosting your repository seeing your activity in the Apache logs there, you have issues far beyond what can be solved with software. You could disable logging in Apache, but your sysadmin can switch it back on or use other means.

Last option: if you don't trust the system(s) and/or network you're on, don't engage in activities that you consider sensitive on them. They can't see something that isn't happening in the first place.

Comment: Thank you! The apache log made me believe the urls were clear, but they are indeed only clear in the log file.

Comment: You can configure Apache to not log full URLs but if you're hosting anything else on the same site/port and need to do log analysis there, it'll be an issue.